# Can Indian dependents on Tier 2 visas apply in the UK for Schengen visas?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I am in the UK on a Tier 2 ICT visa intracompany transfer valid for 1 year. I came to the UK in September 2016 and my visa expires on 24 August 2017. I have my UK resident permit (BRP card), as well.

On 9th March 2017, my wife and newborn joined me in the UK on Tier 2 ICT staff partner and staff child visas as dependents. It's not a visit visa and they don't have a BRP card; the visa is on their passport and is only valid from 28 February to 24 August 2017, my visa end date.

Can we apply for Schengen visas from the UK? We are planning to visit Europe and want to travel over the Easter holidays.

Comment: I would think that you count as residents in the UK *for purposes of the Schengen application*. You can only apply where you live. The time limit on your UK residency will weaken your application, but I can't judge how badly.

Comment: Their policy on proportionality of applicant's residence varies from country to country. From what you wrote, it sounds like a reasonable case can be made, but a *specific member state* must be identified in order to get a technically precise answer. You did not identify the member state, close voting as 'unclear'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the Schengen country where you apply as not all of them have a single definition of what a 'resident' is. However generally you should be fine - the website of the [French Consulate General in London](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/How-and-where-to-apply-for-a-visa) says the following:

> - Your UK residency must have at least 3 months validity after the intended date of departure from the Schengen area.
> - As per the decree 2008-1176 of the 13th of November 2008, the French Consulate, London, is not competent in processing visa applications of people not resident in the UK, i.e. holders of ’C-Visit’ visas or of a British visa valid for 6 months or less. People who are not resident in the UK must apply for their Schengen visas at the French Consulate in their country of residence.

Since your wife stays in the UK on a 'resident' visa and her stay lasts for more than 6 months, it should be okay for your family to apply for a Schengen visa from the UK.